# How to subscribe to param changes in child route?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have these routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  {
    path: 'explore',
    component: ExploreComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: ProductListComponent },
      { path: ':categorySlug', component: ProductListComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

This means that the user can go to

`/explore` (no category)

or

`/explore/computers` (category `computers`)

From the parent (`ExploreComponent`), I want to be able to subscribe to the `categorySlug` param change, and handle the event of course. How can I do this?

**EDIT:**

I tried subscribing using:

`this.activatedRoute.firstChild.params.subscribe(console.log);`

And it gives me exactly what I want, but it dies once I go to `/explore` (without category). It only works when navigating using `/explore/:categorySlug` links.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the `params` in your component ang get the parameter, e.g. like this:

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
          this.categorySlug= params['categorySlug '];
      });

  // do something with this.categorySlug
}
```

**Side note:** In general you use a kind of master detail structure in your web app, so the first path goes to the master and the second one goes to the detail, each served with a different component, but in case that you want to use the same component for both of them, or there is no such a master-detail relationship, you should check if the parameter is null.

Comment: Yes, I'm checking if it's NULL.

Comment: This only prints once.

Comment: @FeloVilches What do you mean by once? Can you explain more about the situation?

Comment: I have a print inside the event handler, and it's only printed once. When I change the route again nothing happens. I'm using `routerLink` in the HTML links.

Comment: I tried subscribing using `this.router.events.subscribe(console.log);` but it gives me a lot of things except what I want.